# drop foreign key constraint not removed completely

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I dropped a foreign key constraint in `users_id` field, and wanted to set field value to allow NULL values, and DEFAULT NULL.

It seems like foreign key constraint has been removed, but somehow I cannot make the field NULL-able.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_internal_team_has_users_users1`;
```

Here's the table schema after dropping foreign key:

```
 CREATE TABLE `internal_team_head` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `internal_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` enum('lead','project_manager') NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`internal_team_id`,`users_id`,`type`),
  KEY `fk_internal_team_has_users_users1_idx` (`users_id`),
  KEY `fk_internal_team_has_users_internal_team1_idx` (`internal_team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_internal_team_has_users_internal_team1` FOREIGN KEY (`internal_team_id`) REFERENCES `internal_team` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=69 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now I want to change `users_id` to allow NULL values and default to NULL.

```
ALTER TABLE `internal_team_head` CHANGE `users_id` `users_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

The Alter query executes successfully but `users_id` `Null` attribute is still set to `No` and default value set to `0`.

How do I enforce the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html):

> - PRIMARY KEY
>
> A unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently).

Solution therefore is, to remove the column from the primary key. Your PK design makes no sense, anyway. The auto_increment column is sufficent as PK. Other columns in an index are only used if the left most column is also used. The row is identified by a unique index (auto_increment) already, so there's no need for that.
Also keep in mind, that you want your PK to be as small as possible. Secondary indexes include the PK to access rows. So try to avoid unnecessary overhead.

Also I'm puzzled, because your question title has nothing to do with your question. But to address that issue also, a `KEY` is not a `FOREIGN KEY`, it's an index. Yes, the naming is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE internal_team_head
ALTER COLUMN users_id INT(11) NULL;
```